# How to select dynamic image from Gallery View in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello all I am newbie on `jQuery` and i am working on one application,
 I need to select an image from `Galary View` in `JQuery`. 
I tried doing this code.

```
// I need to set image dynamically so i am taking ImageIndex as a parameter.
 function OpenImageGallery(sImageIndex) {
        $('#myGallery').galleryView();

            $(function () {
                $("#Divgallery").dialog(
                {
                    width: 840,
                    height: 520,
                    title: 'Hotel Image Gallery'
                }
                ).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
            });
            }
```

but here i am facing one issue is it is showing only default image and not dynamic whose Index i am passing to function.

Please help me friends.

Answer (score 2):

the plugin documentation should have your answer.

Comment: can you please provide me some more details on it? i am fresher and also new in this technology. so your small help will be appreciated. thanks for reply